# Memorize window locations connecting / disconnecting monitor

Tags: windows-10, window-manager

I disconnect move my laptop quite often from the monitor and it takes quite a while to move my windows back.

I've looked around many times, but I couldn't find an app to memorize window locations after connecting / disconnecting monitor.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen it before. However I'd be still happy to see a polished tool managing that.

Comment: What is a "polished tool"? Beggars can't be choosers. I am surprised that there is a solution at all. DisplayFusion is a reputable piece of software so good luck finding a "polished tool"

Comment: DisplayFusion would be great, but they don't support this feature unfortunately.